# spring boot maximum throughput can a rest api like get support

Tags: spring-boot, rest, concurrency, configuration

I was doing a project that needs to support a cluster of 30k nodes, all those nodes periodic calls the api to get data.

I want to have the maximum amount of concurrent get operation per second, and due to it is get operation, it must be in synced way.

And my local pc is 32GB 8Core, spring boot version is 2.6.6, configurations are like

```
server.tomcat.max-connections=10000
server.tomcat.threads.max=800
```

I use jmeter to do concurrent test, and the through out is around 1k/s, average response time is 2 seconds.

Is there any way to make it support more requests per second?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without details on the web service, implementation of what it actually does and where the bottleneck actually is (threads, connections, CPU, memory or others) but, as a general recommendation, using non-blocking APIs would help but it should then be full non-blocking to actually make a real difference.

I mean that just adding Webflux and have blocking DB would not improve so much.

Furthermore, all improvements in execute time would help so check if you can improve the code and maybe have a look at trying to go [native](https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) (which will come "built in" in Boot 3.X btw)

Comment: it is a get service, which simply provides a read operation for a local map (I prefer not to use redis to store the data due the the value is not a simple value), and this means the improve of code side is very limited, by non-blocking api do you mean async way?

Comment: non-blocking is async yes but async might not be non-blocking. In Spring Boot, that would be webflux instead of web (if you don't have any DB you read from or other "external" operations). If I understand you correctly, you read you data from a Map that is in memory so nothing much to win there.

Comment: yeah, with the maximum thread and connections, the qps is 1k/s with reasonable response time, even with udertown, seems very limited to improve

Comment: Probably adding more core is the only "solution" here.

Comment: At least Quarkus native reduces max throughput by 50%. Check their docs. It’s a common misconception that going native boosts performance in regard to throughput.